# Make last few lines of UILabel or UITextView fade out in swift. Please check the attached image

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitextview, fadeout

[image]

How to make control like this?

Comment: Think can replicate by a textview and a button with gradient background (white -> alpha)

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Tj3n:- Thank you, I was thinking about this and you make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have done:

- I created a UIView with a height of my choice, trailing, leading and bottom constraints to the textView.  This is my gradientView which I also use to add additional controls like the 'Read more' button, for example.
- In viewDidLayoutSubviews() I create a gradient layer for the gradientView.  (Note that you need to either remove the layer before creating it or ensure that it is added only once, otherwise your gradient will get darker every time viewDidLayoutSubviews is called)
- When my text change, I determine if the gradientView should be displayed or not by examining `textView.contentSize.height > textView.frame.height`

Herewith a Playground example

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

var gradientView: UIView?
var gradient:CAGradientLayer?

override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .gray

    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 300)
    textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eu gravida ligula, vitae venenatis felis. Suspendisse volutpat posuere pretium. Pellentesque quis quam ac velit tincidunt egestas. Phasellus sed scelerisque augue, interdum luctus eros. Praesent non augue eu enim dignissim convallis. Nunc commodo eros quis quam euismod, a malesuada ipsum mattis. Sed sit amet ipsum in justo dictum rutrum a sit amet sem. Sed sit amet mi vel nulla ornare congue. Nam elit ante, aliquam id consequat ac, pretium vel augue. Vivamus hendrerit commodo lectus, vel feugiat mi tempus non. Donec porta, ipsum id porttitor sodales, tortor lectus porta lacus, quis blandit turpis enim at libero. Donec ante est, rutrum quis malesuada a, accumsan at tortor. Nam molestie commodo nulla non suscipit. Nullam pellentesque nunc quam, vitae tempus turpis sollicitudin id. Integer vel varius urna, eleifend eleifend diam."
    textView.textColor = .black
    view.addSubview(textView)

    let gradientViewFrame = CGRect(x:textView.frame.origin.x, y: textView.frame.origin.y + textView.frame.height - 100, width: textView.frame.width, height: 100)
    gradientView = UIView(frame:gradientViewFrame)
        view.addSubview(gradientView!)
    self.view = view
}

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        gradient?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        gradient = gradientView?.gradientBackground(from:.white, to: UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0), direction: .bottomToTop)
    }
}

enum GradientDirection {
    case leftToRight
    case rightToLeft
    case topToBottom
    case bottomToTop
}

extension UIView {
    func gradientBackground(from color1: UIColor, to color2: UIColor, direction: GradientDirection) -> CAGradientLayer {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]

        switch direction {
        case .leftToRight:
            gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
            gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        case .rightToLeft:
            gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
            gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        case .bottomToTop:
            gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
            gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        case .topToBottom:
            gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
            gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        default:
            break
        }

        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        return gradient
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Comment: @carien van Zyl:- Thank you so much for the time, effort and for the solution. I really appreciate it but this is not fit into my requirement and i have already did that with simple way. But thank you for sharing the solution it might help others.

Comment: @yacc:- I agree of what you've said. I also believe that spoon-fed answer will not help others to think and create solution but this guy made an effort so if you don't have courtesy to appreciate the effort of others then don't do this down vote kinda thing on the answer. show some respect.

Comment: @yacc:- I made it clear that I didn't have problem with your opinion and I also don't have problem that you downvoted my question. I don't even care about points. I am not here to make points like greedy people who care about points. I had problem that you didn't appreciate the effort of others by downvoting answer. Anyway I don't have that much time to come here and answer your rubbish so do your work and let others work.

Comment: @yacc i had to flag your comment. why? questioner had no idea about how to implement and how to start. so Tj3n's comment guided him that how to do. as a plus point Carien posted an answer to help him. I am upvoting him for his efforts. at least give credits for efforts made.

Comment: @yacc i believe SO is free. instead of you should have provide basic developer forum's link like go through this try first instead of mentioning any country name. :)

Comment: Awesomeness mate! Saved my goddamn day! <3 +1